# DirectX primitive doesn't move on screen when rotating camera

Tags: c++, winapi, directx

I'm trying to place a cube on the screen using vertices...i have a camera that rotates and translates with mouse and keyboard commands...during runtime, however, the square surface of the cube lays flat on the screen and doesn't move while the camera is rotating...the other items on the screen appear behind the square surface...can anyone explain the process of rendering a primitive? Thanks in advance for any help...it's much appreciated!

```
#define SQUAREFVF (D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE)

struct SQUARE {
    float x, y, z;
    DWORD color;
};

SQUARE vert[] = 
{
    // 1
        { -64.0f,  -64.0f, 64.0f, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(0,0,0,255)},
        {  -64.0f,  64.0f, 64.0f, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(0,0,0,255)},
        { 64.0f, 64.0f, 64.0f, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(0,0,0,255)},
        {  64.0f, -64.0f, 64.0f, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(0,0,0,255)},
};
bool CGraphics::TerrainTwo(D3DXVECTOR3 minB, D3DXVECTOR3 maxB, int numCellsW, int numCellsL)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    void* pVoid;

    hr = m_d3ddev->CreateVertexBuffer(sizeof(SQUARE)*sizeof(vert),0,
        CUSTOMFVF,D3DPOOL_DEFAULT,&m_terrainVertexBuffer,NULL);
    if(FAILED(hr)){
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Could not Create Vertex Buffer", L"ERROR", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }
    hr = m_terrainVertexBuffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&pVoid, NULL);
    if(FAILED(hr)){
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Could not Lock Vertex Buffer", L"ERROR", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }   
    memcpy(pVoid, &vert, sizeof(vert));
    m_terrainVertexBuffer->Unlock();

    /*hr = m_d3ddev->CreateIndexBuffer(sizeof(DWORD)*sizeof(indices),0,
        D3DFMT_INDEX16, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &m_terrainIndexBuffer, NULL);
    if(FAILED(hr)){
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Could not Create Index Buffer", L"ERROR", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }   
    hr = m_terrainIndexBuffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&pVoid, 0);
    if(FAILED(hr)){
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Could not Create Vertex Buffer", L"ERROR", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }   
    memcpy(pVoid, indices, sizeof(indices));
    if(FAILED(hr)){
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Could not Create Vertex Buffer", L"ERROR", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }   
    m_terrainIndexBuffer->Unlock();*/

    return true;
}
void CGAME::Update()
{

if(m_graphics){
        //m_graphics->UpdateSkyBox();
        D3DXMATRIX matRotX, matRotY, matRotZ, matTrans;

        D3DXMatrixRotationX (&matRotX, 0);
        D3DXMatrixRotationY( &matRotY, 0 );  
        D3DXMatrixRotationZ( &matRotZ, 0 ); 
        // Calculate a translation matrix
        D3DXMatrixTranslation(&matTrans,5.0,1.0,5.0);
        D3DXMATRIX matWorld = (matRotX*matRotY*matRotZ)*matTrans;
        m_graphics->RenderTerrain(matWorld);
    }
}

void CGraphics::RenderTerrain(D3DXMATRIX matW)
{
    m_d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &matW);
    m_d3ddev->SetTexture(0, NULL);
    m_d3ddev->SetStreamSource(0, m_terrainVertexBuffer, 0, sizeof(SQUARE));

    m_d3ddev->SetFVF(CUSTOMFVF);

    m_d3ddev->DrawPrimitive( D3DPT_TRIANGLESTRIP,  0, 2 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's all matrix math. Your cube will be rotated as long as its vertices are transformed by the inverse camera transform (aka camera or view matrix) in the vertex shader (also it should be transformed by its own world transformation matrix and the so called projection matrix, which is responsible for the perspective effect).

Assuming that you have a vertex shader (fixed function pipeline is a bit outdated), all you have to do is make sure that these transformations are applied. Usually, this is done by a single multiplication with a world*view*projection matrix and I'm pretty sure you do it somewhere and it's just not the right one.

There are many good sources on the rendering pipeline, but which one is the right one depends on the DirectX/hardware level you're using (there's a red line that they all share, though, and the *basic* idea how a single primitives comes to the screen hasn't changed much in the past 15 years).

Since you are new to 3D graphics, as I presume, let me warn you: DirectX and OpenGl can be tricky/unintuitive and the math behind 3D graphics in general it is not absolutely trivial, both together will quite often give you the feeling that something just won't move or doesn't even appear on the screen. Just keep debugging, double-checking your code with tutorials or sample code, ... .

Answer (score 0):

Where is matrices of the camera dude? You are setting only a world matrix. Before you call DrawPrimitive, you have to set camera matrices like below.

```
m_d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &matW); // This line is already in your code.
m_d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &camera.m_viewMatrix);
m_d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, &camera.m_projMatrix);
```

You may find the camera matrices somewhere.